# fancytree problems - "Uncaught Error: Assertion failed: expected array of children"

Tags: json, dynatree, jquery-dynatree, fancytree

I'm trying to migrate from dynatree to fancytree.  Even if I try returning the simplest json array from my webmethod I get the error in the subject title: "Uncaught Error: Assertion failed: expected array of children"

The json returned as shown in chrome network tab is:

```
{"d":[{"__type":"test","title":"title1"},{"__type":"test","title":"title2"},{"__type":"test","title":"title3"}]}
```

The exact same json array works perfectly in dynatree. What has changed in the fancytree implementation to break the json compatibility?  This is driving me insane.

Comment: It's something to do with the object array being within the "d" property. If I put the json in a file adn remove that d: property then all works.

Comment: Could you add this as an answer and mark it as 'accepted'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been fixed in a recent release of fancytree which has reinstated the automatic population of the object array if the "d" object is present.